# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap4'. python crash course

Tags: python-3.x, django, bootstrap-4

i am running into that error. at first i had bootstrap3 installed in my project directory. it was throwing the same error after some googling i saw some troubleshoots advising to install bootstrap4 still am facing the same error. i need help. Below is my code.

installing bootstrap4
`pip install django-bootstrap4`

settings.py

```
setting for bootstrap 

bootstrap4 = {
    'include_jquery':True,     
}

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'learning_logs.apps.LearningLogsConfig',
    'users',
    'bootstrap4',
]
```

base.html

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Learning Log</title>
    {% bootstrap_css %}
    {% bootstrap_javascript %}

</head>

<body>
    <!--static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}"> Learning Log</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{% url 'topics' %}">Topics</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li><a>Hello, {{ user.username }}.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}">log out</a></li>
                    {% else %}
                    <li><a href="{% url 'users:register' %}">register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">log in</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            {% block header %}{% endblock header %}
        </div>
        <div>
            {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
        </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you installing `django-bootstrap4` and running `manage.py runserver` from the same active virtual environment? If not, that would explain this error. In the active virtual environment where you're running runserver, you can issue the command `pip freeze`. That will show all the packages you've installed to the environment. If you don't see bootstrap4 listed, it got installed somewhere else. If that's the case, run `pip install django-bootstrap4` from the same terminal where you're running runserver.

Comment: hi.  yes my bootstrap is installed in my active virtual environment. from `pip freeze` i can see  `django-bootstrap4==1.1.1` is installed. However the error still persists. thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how to help then. From a working version of this project, the only way I could recreate this error was to run `pip uninstall django-bootstrap4`. If you are working from the second edition of PCC, there are multiple versions of this project posted at various stages of development. Here's [three versions](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/tree/master/chapter_19) of the project from chapter 19; you could download the repo, copy the version from the end of chapter 19, and pick up at the beginning of chapter 20 if that helps.

Comment: thanks mate i later found away to manoeuvre  the issue by installing bootstrap into static folder

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways than what you are doing to access bootstrap, instead you could just add the bootstrap links as you would normally add them to html code like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

You could also just download the bootstrap files and link it into your static folder.

Comment: Thank you i just installed in my static folder